# Problems using query strings when hiding page extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, query-string

I'm using ASP.NET with C# (Visual Studio 2015). I've implemented the following code snippet in the `Global.asax` file:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Removes requirement of having ".aspx" in the URL
    String WebsiteURL = Request.Url.ToString();
    String[] SplitedURL = WebsiteURL.Split('/');
    String[] Temp = SplitedURL[SplitedURL.Length - 1].Split('.');

    // This is for aspx page
    if (!WebsiteURL.Contains(".aspx") && Temp.Length == 1)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp[0].Trim()))
            Context.RewritePath(Temp[0] + ".aspx");
    }

 }
```

So that instead of forcing an extension in the page URL:

> http://www.example.net/SomePage.aspx

I can leave out the extension to redirect to the same page:

> http://www.example.net/SomePage

The problem is that now if I add a query string to the URL, it can no longer find the page. For example:

> http://www.example.net/SomePage?name=value

results in a 404 Not Found error.

How can I make query strings work even when the extension is hidden?

Comment: Why not check for the `?` character and handle it properly?

Comment: @itsme86 I don't know why not, I nabbed the above code from some other site :-)

Comment: How does one have 11.7k reputation and end up with this question? :) Are you just branching out to C#?

Comment: @itsme86 A great majority of that is Delphi...

Comment: I would rather use the [IIS url rewriter](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for that sort of stuff. [Examples](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Removes requirement of having ".aspx" in the URL
    Uri uri = this.Request.Url;
    string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && path != "/" && path.IndexOf('.') == -1)
    {
        path = path + ".aspx";
        string query = uri.Query;
          string url = path + query;
          Context.RewritePath(url);
    }
 }
```

Try the above code. As VDWWD mentioned, the best approach is use IIS url rewriter instead.

Comment: Although this works, now it adds a brand new problem - the home page no longer defaults without adding the `Default` or `Default.aspx`. Also with a 404 error.

Comment: I changed the code so it will take this into consider.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. C# syntax is one thing, but actually utilizing ASP.NET with it is way beyond me :-)